# I need some help to make a generating function for

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions, moment-generating-functions

.  I need some help to make a generating function for those series (3,6,11,18,...) and (3a1,0,0,3^2 a2,..) .

Comment: It is not very clear what series you want

Comment: For both. I forgot to write that in second I have that generating function  for (a0,a1,a2,...) is sinx + x^2.

Comment: I think he means that the pattern is not clear.

Comment: Your question is not at all clear. What do you mean by "generating function"? Do you mean a function of the natural numbers whose range yields the given values? There are also other meanings for that phrase. And you really need to clarify that second sequence. Also, do you mean "sequence" rather than "series"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one function that gives the first sequence $3,6,11,18,\ldots$ from $1,2,3,4,\ldots$:

$$f(x)=x^2+2$$

Is that what you meant?

---

There are many ways to get that formula from your sequence. Here is one way, close to what I did mentally.

Look at the differences between successive entries, then look at the differences in *that* sequence. Putting each sequence on a line, we get

$$\begin{matrix}
 3 &   & 6 &   & 11 &   & 18 \\
   & 3 &   & 5 &    & 7 &    \\
   &   & 2 &   & 2 &    &    \\
\end{matrix}$$

We see that the entries in the third row are equal. That means that our desired formula is a quadratic polynomial. The repeated value in the third row is $2$. In a way similar to integrating the constant $2$ twice and getting $x^2+bx+c$, that repeated $2$ means our quadratic has a leading coefficient of $1$.

There are ways to quickly get the values of $b$ and $c$, but a quick look at your sequence immediately let me see that the correct formula is $x^2+2$.

This kind of analysis is called the Calculus of Finite Differences, and I got my introduction to that in one of Martin Gardner's columns in the Mathematical Games department of Scientific American magazine. That column was reprinted with comments in Gardner's book *New Mathematical Diversions from Scientific American*. The main theorem in that study is that an $n$'th degree polynomial gives constant values in the $n+1$'th row of finite differences, and that value is $n!$ times the leading coefficient of the polynomial.

Comment: Yes, but can you explane me how you  made it?